# Calling execve bash on bash scripts can't find arguments

Tags: c, linux, bash

I have two (Ubuntu Linux) bash scripts which take input arguments. They need to be run simultaneously. I tried `execve` with arguments e.g.

`char *argv[10] = { "/mnt/hgfs/F/working/script.sh", "file1", "file2", NULL  };`

`execve(argv[0], argv, NULL)`

but the bash script can't seem to find any arguments at e.g. `$0`, `$1`, `$2`.

```
printf "gcc -c ./%s.c -o ./%s.o\n" $1 $1;
gcc -c ./$1.c -o ./$1.o -g
exit 0;
```

output is `gcc -c ./main.c -o ./main.o`
and then a lot of errors like `/usr/include/libio.h:53:21: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory`

What's missing?

Comment: Passing a NULL environment is unlikely to make the shell happy...

Comment: a little off topic, but somewhat relevant... you can use: extern char *environ; //it will grab what you need for envp ... or you can start your program with argc, argv and envp and use envp from that

Comment: Just use `execv` rather than `execve` if you don't want to provide a new environment.

Answer (score 5):

Does your script start with the hashbang line? I think that's a must, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

For example, see the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *argv[10] = { "./qq.sh", "file1", NULL };
int main (void) {
    int rc = execve (argv[0], argv, NULL);
    printf ("rc = %d\n", rc);
   return 0;
}
```

When this is compiled and run with the following `qq.sh` file, it outputs `rc = -1`:

```
echo $1
```

when you change the file to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

it outputs:

```
file1
```

as expected.

---

The other thing you need to watch out for is with using these VMWare shared folders, evidenced by `/mnt/hgfs`. If the file was created with a Windows-type editor, it may have the "DOS" line endings of `carriage-return/line-feed` - that may well be causing problems with the execution of the scripts.

You can check for this by running:

```
od -xcb /mnt/hgfs/F/working/script.sh
```

and seeing if any `\r` characters appear.

For example, if I use the shell script with the hashbang line in it (but appen a carriage return to the line), I *also* get the `rc = -1` output, meaning it couldn't find the shell.

---

And, now, based on your edits, your script has *no* trouble interpreting the arguments at all. The fact that it outputs:

```
gcc -c ./main.c -o ./main.o
```

is proof positive of this since it's seeing `$1` as `main`.

The problem you actually have is that the compiler *is* working but it cannot find `strdarg.h` included from your `libio.h` file - this has nothing to do with whether `bash` can see those arguments.

My suggestion is to try and compile it manually with that command and see if you get the same errors. If so, it's a problem with what you're trying to compile rather than a `bash` or `exec` issue.

If it does compile okay, it *may* be because of the destruction of the environment variables in your `execve` call.

Comment: Yes each script starts with `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @T.Webster, then you need to show us the script since it plainly works (as per my answer). It may be that something is wrong with the way you're trying to access `$n`, or it may be an encoding issue with the script file itself.

Comment: Updated with the script. The script is edited and saved from Linux.

Comment: the script is posted but still having trouble. please look when you have time.